# Ant Design how to link form to chart?

Tags: forms, antd

I have a two column layout, left is a pie chart, right is a form where you can change values and if satisfied save the configuration. Instead of my current code, which only let the pie chart present the saved state, I want it to be updated as soon as the form is changed. How can I do so?

```
<Row>
    <Col md={12} lg={12}>
        <ChartPie portfolio={portfolio} />
    </Col>
    <Col md={12} lg={12}>
        <Form form={form} initialValues={portfolio} onFinish={onFinish}>
            <Form.List name="stocks">
            {(entries, { add, remove, move }) => (
                <AllocationTable
                form={form}
                data={entries}
                add={add}
                remove={remove}
                move={move}
                />
            )}
            </Form.List>
            <br />
            <Row justify="end">
            <Form.Item>
                <Button type="default" onClick={onReset}>
                Reset
                </Button>
            </Form.Item>
            <Form.Item>
                <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" style={{ marginLeft: 8 }}>
                Submit
                </Button>
            </Form.Item>
            </Row>
        </Form>
    </Col>
</Row>
```

Comment: Pass the states has declared for form to ChartPie as props and check its updates in useEffect.(in ChartPie component)

Comment: Right but how can I retrieve the "values" from the form instance? Or can I sync link the form to my portfolio object?